# parsing XML and show it into table using SOAP

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

im getting query result in Web Service and sending it to Client Service I've converted the result to XML by using this:

```
   try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);

        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM  information_schema.collations where id like '%84%'");

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Element row = doc.createElement("Row");
            results.appendChild(row);
            for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++) {
                String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                Object value = rs.getObject(i);
                Element node = doc.createElement(columnName);
                node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value.toString()));
                row.appendChild(node);
            }
        }
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(sw);
        transformer.transform(domSource, sr);

        System.out.println(sw.toString());

        conn.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get connection", e);
    }
```

is this considered as a right way?
how to send it to client service?
how to show it in a table?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the right way, greatly depends on the problem you are trying to solve.

Usually it is not a very good usage of XML to just map a database table to a XML document in a rather generic way (also make sure that the ISO-8859-1 encoding is really what you want, that is you do not have any special characters in your data and also do not expect this application to run with data covering different languages).

You can achieve a lot more by defining objects with structure and relationships and such. 
If you already have an object structure representing your data in a better way, there is also some libraries with which you can map those data structures to XML (e.g JAXB or XStream are two often used librariers for XML serialization).

Explain more what you try to achieve and you might receive better answers.